# Drag drop item inside Uniform grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF so please bear with me. In a UniformGrid I put multiple UserControls which are created at run time. What I want to know is how to drag and drop, move or swap the position of these controls at run time. I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find anything fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

The `UniformGrid` is a layout control. You cannot interact directly with it.

To achieve what you need, I propose you this solution.

1. Create a `ItemsControl` element
2. Change the `ItemsPanel` to a `UniformGrid`
3. Use the [GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop project](http://punker76.github.io/gong-wpf-dragdrop/). You can install it from nuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

This solution can be written without any code-behind or VM code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ItemsControl Height="150" 
             dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
             dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.Items>
          <system:String>Item 1</system:String>
          <system:String>Item 2</system:String>
          <system:String>Item 3</system:String>
        </ItemsControl.Items>

    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

**Update:**

If you need to drag items from another control then add this to your code-behind file.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        SourceOfItems = new List<string>() { "Source 1", "Source 2", "Source 3" };
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; private set; }

    public List<string> SourceOfItems { get; private set; }
}
```

And update your XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <StackPanel>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceOfItems}"
             dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
             dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="False"/>

    <ItemsControl Height="150" 
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  Background="Plum"
                  >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: How can I add items in ItemsControl dynamically at runtime ? As I am doing in uniform grid in which I drag and drop item at runtime.

Comment: Bind the ItemsControl ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection<T>. Do you need help for that?

Comment: But it has one issue. Drag Drop from left to right is not working in it. Can I have a solution for that ?

Comment: and one more thing I am creating my usercontrol on Drop event of Uniformgrid. How can I do this in your code ?

Comment: If this answer your question, then, please accept it. If you have other questions related to the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop check the website or ask another question of SO.